# How to combine a wide and a long dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have the following dataframe

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Height':[23, 43, 123, 12], 'Hair_Width':[21, 11, 23, 14]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df

    Name    Age Height  Hair_Width
0   Tom     20  23      21
1   nick    21  43      11
2   krish   19  123     23
3   jack    18  12      14
```

I performed a melt operation on this dataframe as follows:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
df
    Name    variable    value  
0   Tom     Age         20     
1   nick    Age         21     
2   krish   Age         19     
3   jack    Age         18     
4   Tom     Height      23     
5   nick    Height      43     
6   krish   Height      123    
7   jack    Height      12
```

However, I would like to combine the new melted dataframe with a variable from the original (wide) dataframe, to get the following desired output:

```
    Name    variable    value  Hair_Width
0   Tom     Age         20     21
1   nick    Age         21     11
2   krish   Age         19     23
3   jack    Age         18     14
4   Tom     Height      23     21
5   nick    Height      43     11
6   krish   Height      123    23
7   jack    Height      12     14
```

I would love to hear any suggestions on how this can be accomplished.

Edit: A lot of people correctly pointed out that the original dataset is in tidy format. That is correct- it is just used as a simple example. The actual data frame is not tidy to start.

Comment: The original dataframe isn't wide. It looks like it's in tidy format and ought not be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `Hair_Width` as another `id_var` when you `melt`, no need to do anything after.

---

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Hair_Width'], value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
```

```
    Name  Hair_Width variable  value
0    Tom          21      Age     20
1   nick          11      Age     21
2  krish          23      Age     19
3   jack          14      Age     18
4    Tom          21   Height     23
5   nick          11   Height     43
6  krish          23   Height    123
7   jack          14   Height     12
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other questions, I am not sure why you'd like to reshape to long in the first place, but you can easily achieve this with method chaining.

```
newdf = (df
         .melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
         .merge(df[['Name', 'Hair_Width']], how='left', on='Name'))
```

Output:

```
    Name variable  value  Hair_Width
0    Tom      Age     20          21
1   nick      Age     21          11
2  krish      Age     19          23
3   jack      Age     18          14
4    Tom   Height     23          21
5   nick   Height     43          11
6  krish   Height    123          23
7   jack   Height     12          14
```

Or do it in two stages as in

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
newdf = melted.merge(df[['Name', 'Hair_Width']], how='left', on='Name')
```

Output:

```
    Name variable  value  Hair_Width
0    Tom      Age     20          21
1   nick      Age     21          11
2  krish      Age     19          23
3   jack      Age     18          14
4    Tom   Height     23          21
5   nick   Height     43          11
6  krish   Height    123          23
7   jack   Height     12          14
```

Answer (score 1):

So you've got your data input and melting process (honestly unsure why you've decided to melt it anyway, because the original data appears to be in tidy format):

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Height':[23, 43, 123, 12], 'Hair_Width':[21, 11, 23, 14]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
```

I've provided the names I used above. Do a merge, and poof:

```
new_df.merge(df[['Name', 'Hair_Width']], on='Name', how='left')
Out[25]: 
    Name variable  value  Hair_Width
0    Tom      Age     20          21
1   nick      Age     21          11
2  krish      Age     19          23
3   jack      Age     18          14
4    Tom   Height     23          21
5   nick   Height     43          11
6  krish   Height    123          23
7   jack   Height     12          14
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```
df_out = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Age', 'Height'])
df_out['Hair_Width'] = df_out['Name'].map(df.set_index('Name')['Hair_Width'])
df_out
```

Output:

```
    Name variable  value  Hair_Width
0    Tom      Age     20          21
1   nick      Age     21          11
2  krish      Age     19          23
3   jack      Age     18          14
4    Tom   Height     23          21
5   nick   Height     43          11
6  krish   Height    123          23
7   jack   Height     12          14
```